# Integração com MailChimp

Tags: php

Bom eu estou fazendo uma integração com MailChimp, utilizando este código:

```
require('src/Mailchimp.php');
define('MAILCHIMP_API_KEY',  '6db8ab94ce74d88a289f9068768d7179-us9'); // Mailchimp API KEY
define('MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID',  'c825a91eb8'); // ID Lista
define('MAILCHIMP_CITY_TAG', 'MERGE1'); // Tag Do campo

$email = [
        'email' => "teste@teste.com.br",
    ];
$merge = [
        MAILCHIMP_CITY_TAG => "testando",
    ];

try {
    $mailchimp = new Mailchimp(MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);
    $lists = new Mailchimp_Lists($mailchimp);


$lists->subscribe(
  MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, // Lista id
  $email,            // Email
  $merge,            // Campo personalizado
  'html',            // Tipo de Email
  false              // Confirmação email


 );
echo 'Sucesso!';



  } catch (Mailchimp_List_AlreadySubscribed $e) {
    echo 'Você já assinou essa lista!.';
  } catch (Mailchimp_Email_NotExists $e) {
    echo 'O e-mail informado não existe.';
  } catch (Mailchimp_Invalid_Email $e) {
    echo 'O e-mail informado é inválido.';
  } catch (Mailchimp_List_InvalidImport $e) {
    echo 'Dados inválidos, provavelmente seu e-mail.';
  } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
  }
```

Porém eu tenho uma tabela no banco de dados que contém a API KEY do cliente e o ID da lista. Ou seja, eu quero pegar os valores do banco de dados, salvá-los numa variável e definir os mesmos com esses valores.
Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: Mysql, mas o problema não é no banco de dados. Eu consigo capturar esses valores tudo certinho, salvei eles em variáveis também tudo certinho, o que quero saber é como especifico que API KEY recebe o valor dessa variável. Pois só consigo setar esse valor com o define.

Comment: Bom, e você não pode substituir os `define` por variáveis com estes valores do banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando este código :

```
require('src/Mailchimp.php');
$apikey = '6db8ab94ce74d88a289f9068768d7179-us9';
$merge_vars =  array('MERGE1' => 'testando');
$email = 'teste@teste.com.br';
$listid = 'c825a91eb8';
$MailChimp = new Mailchimp($apikey);
$result = $MailChimp->lists->subscribe($listid,
                                    array('email'=>$email),
                                    $merge_vars,
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    false
                                   );
```